# Mathematical terminology about Holomorphic vector bundle over Grassmanian.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, mathematical-physics, grassmannian, moduli-space, mirror-symmetry

This question is relevant to Mirror symmetry and moduli space.

The linear sigma model in $U(k)$ with $Nk$ chiral fields vacua equation can be reduced as
\begin{align}
  \sum_{i,j=1}^k \left(\sum_s^N \bar{\phi}_{is}\phi^{js}-\delta_i^{\phantom{i}j}r\right)=0
\end{align}
The solution of $\phi$ is know as Grassmanian $Gr(k, N)$ 
There is some comment on this in witten's "The Verlinde Algebra and the cohomology of the Grassmannian" paper, which seems plausible, but i don't get it matematically.

Thus first i want to know why this vacua space is Grassmannian $Gr(k, N)$ in mathematically.

---

Next, I want to know the terminology of " Holomorphic vector bundle over Grassmanian."

For the linear sigma model in $U(k)$ $N_f k$ fundamental chrial fields with $N_a k$ anti-fundamental chiral fields the solution of vaccua equation Holomorphic vector bundle $N_a$ over Grassmanian $Gr(k, N_f)$.

I want to know what this means.